# Why does my cat chatter at me when he's being bad and I yell at him?

Tags: cats, psychology

When my cat is doing something he knows is bad, such as trying to chew on flowers, I will snap my fingers and say his name and he will chatter back at me. He will stop doing it, but I'm just curious as to why he chatters at me.

Comment: What kind of cat do you have?  Are you saying that the cat uses the same sound to respond to you as when he sees a bird outside?

Comment: Could you link to a video of what you mean by "chattering"? It doesn't have to be of your cat exactly, just of the behaviour you're talking about.

Comment: My cat does that same thing its so funny. If other people are around I act as if my cat is talking back to me so I tell her "do not talk back" or "do not talk to me like that" I usually ask her questions and when she chatters it only seems she is saying no or maybe apologizing or even trying to explain herself. Either way its pretty funny and i cant be mad

Answer (score 4):

<sub>*You don't really describe the vocalization, so let me know if I am way off the mark.*</sub>

[**Example of cat chattering**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iaiR14JQlOU)

Cat "chattering" is a typical vocalization response when a cat sees a bird or a rodent outside a window. It is typically thought that they chatter in a state of high anticipation or possibly frustration in response to the surge of adrenaline.

A recent study suggeststhat cats may actually be trying to imitate various sounds they hear as a hunting technique.

[**Cats that copy and impersonate other animals**](http://www.thedailycat.com/behavior/understanding/copy_cat/index.html#axzz3uJvRWtfe)

[YouTube is full of videos](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=talking+cats&aq=f) of cats coincidentally or intentionally trying to make human-like sounds. Who knows; maybe he's trying to tell you to stop *beotching* at him so much <grin>.

Answer (score 2):

I've heard a claim that the rapid jaw motion in the "chitter" is actually a specialized bite, which works the teeth between the prey's vertebre to sever the spinal column. I have no credible citation, alas, but I've alwsys interpreted it as "I'd bite that, but I can't." Maybe in this case it's "I'd bite that but I'd get my furry butt whipped" -- another form of feline cursing to go with hiss, yowl, and the time my siamese pointedly made burying motions in my direction.